# I am trying to install jomsocial 4.0.9 on the joomla version 2.5.16 and it gives me the error "JFolder :: create: infinite loop detected Warning! -

Tags: joomla, warnings

I am trying to install jomsocial 4.0.9 on the joomla version 2.5.16 and it gives me the error:

> JFolder :: create: infinite loop detected
>   Warning! - The file can not be moved!

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me to solve this issue ???

Comment: i think there is no one on the stack overflow who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you gave too less details. It would be helpful if we know what you tried to do, what action did you take to result error above.

I'm guessing that you tried to upload a file (installation? photo upload?).

It seems like your tmp directory may not have been defined properly.
Check what values are defined for the log and tmp paths in configuration.php

This may also helps: https://docs.joomla.org/Archived:Infinite_loop_detected_in_JError_in_Joomla_1.7